# Usage of 'the' before American/African etc

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is the usage of 'the' correct in the sentences below?

> The taco was spicier than **the** American one.
>
> The sushi was less expensive than **the** Japanese one.

I was asked by my friend why are we using 'the' here when we are comparing it with general tacos or sushis. I'm unable to explain it. We both are non-native English speakers.

Comment: **the** doesn't really come before "American" or "Japanese" here, it comes before **one**.  "American" or "Japanese" or "African" are just adjectives in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, "the" is a definite article used when a speaker wishes to refer to an item whose specific identity those in the conversation are familiar.

For example, "the taco was spicier than an American one" (using the indefinite article a/an) says that the taco was spicier than ordinarily/generally found in the U.S.; saying "the American one" indicates one specific taco and implies that two tacos were being compared, one American and one non-American.

Comment: Yes, but it might be worth editing to make the point that although an article is *necessary* before a singular noun (as OP's ***one*** here), it's not syntactically required before the plural form: ***...spicier than [the] American ones.***

Answer (score 1):

Generally, **we compare things that are similar.**

So, you would not compare a taco to the "American one".

If there are two types of tacos, American and Mexican (which is a bit weird since tacos are originally Mexican), you would say:
- The American taco was spicier than the Mexican one.

**The** is used because  you have just eaten those **two types of tacos**. They are specific, and you are not making a general statement about tacos.

As for sushi, it really is only Japanese. So, to compare like things (fish), we would say:

- The sushi was less expensive than the salmon. [on a menu]

The rule about article **the** here is that you are talking about a specific food item you have just eaten. **You are not making general statements.**

Sushi is less expensive than salmon. or Tacos are great.